# Single question: Find the package Doc?

Tags: discussion, questions

Today [another
question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191877/37907) came up on
how the documentation for a command or a package can be found.

There are some similar ones, but all different in a way:
[LaTeX, package documentation look-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62653/37907)
[Finding package documentation [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81960/37907)
[Documentation for the animate package with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104242/37907)

Some Q/A's deal with a special environment, e.g. [Where do I find
documentation for packages in a MiKTeX
installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169137/37907)

Some can't be answered with the simple `texdoc <packageName>`:
[Where is the documentation for the nth package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74434/37907)
[fp package documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122774/37907)

*Do you see the need for a constructed canonical Q/A (community-Wiki)?*

There are different things that have to be considered:

- CTAN provides the most recent doc, but that might not fit with the version installed on the user machine.
- The problem with a possible version discrepancy is true for [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/), as well.
- `texdoc` behaves different in MikTeX and TeX Live (since it is an alias for `mthelp` under MikTeX).
- How can i find out where the command i need help with is defined?

Comment: I think this may be the closest canonical community wiki Q: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27636/which-books-can-i-read-via-texdoc, texdoc.net is not updated frequently, http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html and mirrored url is preferable for eg: beamer http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I tried to put the question in a nutshell, but the current state doesn't satisfy me at all.

> When working with LaTeX one often finds the need to look
>   something up in order to use a command correctly or learn about
>   the basics.
>
> But where can i find the documentation for a package installed
>   with my TeX distribution? Where can i find it for packages not
>   installed?
>
> If i have an unknown command, how can i find out which package
>   defined it?

Right now it seems too broad. Please suggest as much improvements as possible.

Comment: You're right that the entire LaTeX ecosystem lacks consistent structure (or even infrastructure in places). My colleagues' only recourse was to take apart the source codes themselves (a work product I obviously cannot publish here). For the foreseeable future, there will be no consistent framework for contributors to LaTeX and friends. The fact that there never was might be testament to a lack of political/corporate will, but I believe is better explained by the lack of software engineering know-how (LaTeX community is possibly mostly hard science and psychology).